# Universal Redirect Script

Tags: php, asp.net

Is there a way to set up a redirect script that reads the file name and automatically redirects the browser to another file name with a different extension. Eg the user will go to  shop.aspx the file name will automaticly get read by the script and redirect the user to shop.php. I would do this manually but there are lots of files that need to be edited.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this kind of thing - what web server are you working with? Apache or IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to look at your .htaccess file. [Here's](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/) a great guide that actually goes through what you are suggesting. If you want the .aspx files to be handled by php you could add a handler:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .aspx
```

Or if you just want to re-direct from one to the other you could use ModRewrite:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule    ^(.*)\.aspx$ /$1.php [R=301,NC]
```